# Unknown server tag 'asp:ScriptManager'

Tags: asp.net, ajax

```
Line 115:    <div>
Line 116:        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
Line 117:        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
Line 118:        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
Line 119:       <div style="width:100%; background-color:#2A5188; color:White;">
```

I have used this code in master page before asp updatepanel and get error unknown server tag ‘asp:scriptmanager’.

Answer (score 1):

The tagprefix in your `@register` and the tag in front of the scriptmanager i.e. here `asp` must match.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

It fixed an issue I had when running my app deployed on a specific Win Server 2016 box (running .NET 4.6.1).